# I want to use functions in php class. How to use them?

Tags: php, autoload

I know the autoload mechanism, but I don't want to use it （_autoload() or spl_autoload_register），I want to simply php function files.But this doesn't work.

System：

```
php 7.3.x
nginx : 1.15.x
```

file:

```
| - index.php
| - Code
     |- Code.php
     |- Medoo.php
     |- HelperDateTime.php
     .....
```

Code.php:

```
class Code{

     public function Run(){
         include "./Medoo.php";
         include "./HelperDateTime.php";
         ....
     }
}
```

index.php:

```
require 'Code.php';
Code::Run();

// medoo not work
$database = new medoo();
print_r($database);
```

php Beginners, please advise :)

Comment: I think you might need to change `public function Run(){` to a static function like this: `public static function Run(){`

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? I think no error in your given code. Check with your Medoo file.

Comment: where is class `metoo` declared ? show that code too

Answer (score 0):

Index.php

```
<?php
include "Code/Medoo.php";
include "Code/HelperDateTime.php";
require 'Code.php';
Code::Run();

// medoo will work
$database = new medoo();
print_r($database);
?>
```